# Replace all occurrences of a text pattern within a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains a lot of wordpress image names with various image sizes. For example:

```
imgr-3sdfsdf9-266x200.png, pics-asf39-266x800.png, ruh-39-150x200.png
```

What I need to do is replace all the image sizes in this kind of a string with a string "150x150". The string might have hundreds of different filenames with different sizes.
So far all sizes are in format dddxddd - 3 digits folowed by 'x' followed by another 3 digits.I don't think I will have 4 digit width or height.
Always, the size is just before the .png extension.
So after processing the above mentioned string it should become this:

```
imgr-3sdfsdf9-150x150.png, pics-asf39-150x150.png, ruh-39-150x150.png
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Obligatory "what have you tried?"

Comment: I have tried to use a nested str_replace() function with a different size (needle) in each level but that is not an elegant solution. It works fine if I only have 3 or 4 different sizes that have to be replaced, but in the future I will have a lot of different sizes, and nesting more and more str_replace for each size is very nasty. So I need to find a better more elegant way.

Comment: You want [`preg_replace`](http://uk1.php.net/preg_replace) and in the regex you'll make use of some `\d` s a couple of `+`s and possibly some parentheses `()`

Comment: Thanks SmokeyPHP, I will do some reading on preg_replace. Looks exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$size = 150;
echo preg_replace(
  '#\d{3,4}x\d{3,4}\.#is',
  "{$size}x{$size}.",
  'imgr-3sdfsdf9-266x200.png, pics-asf39-266x800.png, ruh-39-150x200.png'
);
```

Comment: Error dans "$sizex$size." .  $sizex will be a variable.

Comment: @jacouh yup, thanks, haven't checked.

Comment: so the d{3,4} means any number which is either 3 or 4 digits long, right? Also, what does the \ do? is it just like an escape character?

Comment: @alwaysStuck Yes, and yes, it's a character class and needs to be escaped in order to *work*, http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html

Comment: Ok, regex starts to make sense now. Good answer and a good link. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That will be something like:

```
$string = 'imgr-3sdfsdf9-266x200.png, pics-asf39-266x800.png, ruh-39-150x200.png';
$string = preg_replace('/(\d{3}x\d{3})\./', '150x150.', $string);
```

-in this I'm relying that after size there will be `.` as file extension delimiter. If it's not so, you may want to remove this from replacement condition.

Answer (score 2):

Using **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**, you can achieve what you want like this:

```
$pattern = '/\d+x\d+(\.png)/i';
$replace = '150x150${1}';
$newStr  = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $initialStr);
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/YpIHM5)**.

***Short explanations***

```
RegEx-pattern:
                       /\d+x\d+(\.png)/i
                        \_/V\_/\_____/ V
       _________         | | |    |    |   ________________
      |Match one|________| | |    |    |__|Make the search |
      |or more  |    ______| |    |___    |case-insensitive|
      |digits   |   |        |        |
             _______|_   ____|____   _|_______________
            |Match the| |Match one| |Match the string |
            |character| |or more  | |'.png' and create|
            |'x'      | |digits   | |a backreference  |

Replacement string:
                     150x150${1}
                     \_____/\__/
     ________________   |    |   ________________________
    |Replace with the|__|    |__|...followed by the 1st  |
    |string '150x150'|          |captured backreference  |
                                |(e.g.: ".png" or ".PNG")|
```